# ServiceStack authorization with Google Oauth only if already registered as credentials user

Tags: authentication, oauth, servicestack, google-oauth

I'm working on a web application that will have both credentials and oauth2 (google/ linkedin) authentication/ authorization. The users will be registered by an admin and given credentials.
In addition the users once registered can authenticate through oauth2 as well.

The issue is that Oauth2 providers if successfully authenticated with Google/ Linkedin will authorize the request in the site despite the user not existing at all. They automatically create records for UserAuth and UserAuthDetail in the repository.

Is there a way to override this default behaviour and instead check whether the user exists or not?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OAuth providers work like you describe. If user is new to site and does not want to invent and remember yet another password, he/she has an option to use available OAuth provider and ServieStack will create the user account for him/her.

If existing user, who uses Credentials provider to login into the site, decides to login via the OAuth provider there are two possible scenarios:

1. If user *IS NOT* logged in and uses OAuth provider, then new user account will be created
2. If user *IS* logged in and uses OAuth provider, then existing account will be bound to this OAuth provider.

If you need to override this, you can just subclass GoogleOAuth2Provider and override `SaveUserAuth` which by default uses `IUserAuthRepository.CreateOrMergeAuthSession()`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll go sub-classing the OAuth Providers, anyway I believe it would be useful for the IUserAuthRepository.CreateOrMergeAuthSession() to have a parameter indicating whether a new user should be created if not existing.

Comment: Hi, it looks like in [AuthProvider.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AuthProvider.cs),  SaveUserAuth is not being called, it is commented out in OnAuthenticated `if (tokens != null)
                {
                    authInfo.ForEach((x, y) => tokens.Items[x] = y);
                    session.UserAuthId = authRepo.CreateOrMergeAuthSession(session, tokens);
                }
                //SaveUserAuth(authService, userSession, authRepo, tokens);`

Comment: Hello. Then you do not need SaveUserAuth :) Instead, override OnAuthenticated and reuse bits of base class code to achieve the exact behavior you need.

Comment: Hi, finally I overrided the Authenticate method of OAuth2Provider, and created(copied) Goggle and LinkedIn providers that depend on the new derived class. I did it earlier in the flow since OnAuthenticated assumes that the user has already been authenticated while i didn't want it that way. As for the SaveUserAuth just wanted to remark that althoug the method is defined it is never called in the library. Thanks